# Decoding CFG for odd length string-:

Tags: context-free

```
S → aX | bX
X→ aS | bS | ε
```

This is required cfg, I want to learn how we arrived at this cfg? What steps did we follow to arrive here? Do we memorize some standard cfgs? I can derive strings using this but that is not useful when I don't know the cfg already.

I have solved a cfg on my own and came up with this, if you can tell me logic like this.
So I thought strings would be ,b,aab,aba,abb,aaa, baa,bab,bba,bbb.

SO cfg will be-:

```
S->aP|aQ|aR|aS|bP|bQ|bR|bS

p->aPa
Q->aQb
R->bRa
S->bSb
```

This is wrong I know but this is the type of logic I love to solve problems with. i.e take "a" or "b" then combine that with even length strings, that gives me odd length string

Comment: What does "decode CFG", "require CFG" and "solve CFG" mean?

Comment: I mean I want to learn how we got to this answer that is what I mean. Is this memorization?

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is *regular*. This means that it describes an NFA, which is in this case deterministic. Here is the DFA which was used to construct your grammar:

[image: Automaton]

Each transition in this automaton corresponds to a rule:

- The transition from $S$ to $X$ labeled $a$ corresponds to $S \to aX$.
- The transition from $S$ to $X$ labeled $b$ corresponds to $S \to bX$.
- The transition from $X$ to $S$ labeled $a$ corresponds to $X \to aS$.
- The transition from $X$ to $S$ labeled $b$ corresponds to $X \to bS$.

Every final state also corresponds to a rule:

- $X$ being a final state corresponds to $X \to \epsilon$.

Finally, the starting symbol is the same as the starting state, in this case $S$.

Whenever your language is regular, you can similarly construct a DFA (or in fact, an NFA), and convert it to a regular grammar in this fashion.

Comment: I need cfg not regular grammar. Are you sure this is cfg? This looks like it though.

Comment: Every regular grammar is context-free. It's like saying "I need a real number, not an integer".